Force zero when conditions are met in a ODE
I'm working on a model that simulates pesticide dynamics in a rice field using a system of differential equations. One of the compartments in my model is the mass of pesticide in the water (mw). According to my logic, mw should be zero whenever dw_t, the water depth, is zero. To enforce this, I've included the following line in my model:
mw <- (mw - sol_diff) * (dw_t > 0)

However, after running the simulation using ode45 from the deSolve package in R, I noticed that mw does not always go to zero when dw_t is zero. Instead, it retains very small non-zero values. I've already adjusted the relative and absolute tolerances (rtol = 1e-12, atol = 1e-16), but the issue persists.
Why is mw not being set to zero as expected, and what can I do to ensure it is exactly zero when dw_t is zero? I don't know if this is a problem of numerical accuracy or an implementation error.
Here is the full code for context:
Input data and aproximation functions:

precipitation_vector <- c(0, 0, 0.16, 1.02, 0.4, 0, 3.46, 0.74, 0, 0.06, 0.06, 0.1, 0.12, 
                          0.04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.72, 0.28, 0.56, 0, 
                          0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0.54, 0.06, 0, 0, 0.24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.28, 
                          0, 1.46, 0.02, 0.08, 1.54, 0.08, 0, 0.12, 0.02, 0.06, 0, 0, 0, 
                          0, 0.02, 0, 1.86, 0.44, 0, 1.88, 0.18, 0.36, 0.96, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 
                          0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0.02, 0.08, 0.44, 0.04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                          0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.36, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 2.96, 
                          0.04, 0, 0.02, 0.02, 0.3, 0.02, 0, 0, 0.46, 0.36, 0.02, 0.02, 
                          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.08, 0.02, 2.54, 0, 0, 0, 0.38, 0, 0.46, 0, 0.8, 
                          0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.06, 0, 0, 0, 0.56, 0.7, 
                          0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.08, 0.02, 0, 0.14, 0, 0.02, 0.22, 0.04, 0, 
                          0.24, 0, 0.06, 0.84, 0.24, 0, 0.72, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.62, 0, 0.32, 0, 0, 0, 0.18, 0.02, 0, 0.02, 
                          0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.74, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.04, 7.58, 0.1, 0, 1.24, 0, 0, 0.38, 0, 0, 0, 
                          0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.56, 0, 0.5, 3.62, 
                          0.42, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 
                          0, 0.02, 0, 0.1, 0.02, 0.14, 0, 0.02, 0, 0.02, 0.38, 0, 0, 0, 
                          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.08, 
                          1.04, 0.14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0.68, 0.02, 0, 0.14, 0, 0.02, 
                          0.02, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.42, 0, 0.34, 0.18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                          0, 0, 0, 0.02)


mapp_vector <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.03, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

igrow_vector <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 
                  3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
                  20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
                  36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
                  52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 
                  68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 
                  84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 
                  100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 
                  113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 
                  126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 
                  139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 
                  152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 
                  165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 
                  178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 
                  191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 
                  204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 
                  217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 
                  230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242)


dw_vector <- c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.20959, 0.21295, 0.21171, 0.24563, 0.25184, 
               0.24923, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.19764, 0.1954, 0.1938, 0.19302, 
               0.19222, 0.18964, 0.18817, 0.18702, 0.18613, 0.18537, 0.19191, 
               0.18537, 0.18537, 0.184, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
               0, 0, 0, 0.01206, 0, 0.01395, 0.01355, 0.01212, 0.02612, 0, 0, 
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01722, 0.0202, 0.00952712992774365, 
               0.0269071299277437, 0.0270071299277437, 0.0295271299277436, 0.0371371299277437, 
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00319, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02856, 0.02799, 
               0.0258, 0, 0, 0.00095, 0, 0, 0, 0.00298, 0.00368, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02381, 0.07002, 0.11684, 0.11182, 0.100029357270849, 
               0.09465, 0.09465, 0.08964, 0.0931, 0.08465, 0.07952, 0.07626, 
               0.07065, 0.06534, 0.06035, 0.05519, 0, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
               0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 0, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
               0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
               0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
               0.1, 0.05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
               0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
               0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
               0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
               0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
               0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.17322, 0.102344238694367, 
               0.1, 0.11098, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02388, 0.02043, 0.0229, 0.0579, 0.06045, 
               0.05801, 0.05612, 0.05383, 0.05159, 0.04953, 0.04769, 0.04558, 
               0.04384, 0.04208, 0.04014, 0.03745, 0.03474, 0.0326, 0.0306, 
               0.02901, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.20974, 0.2, 
               0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.20524, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
               0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
               0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)

vw_vector <- c(c(22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 24078.07206061, 24464.07483805, 
                 24321.62143209, 28218.41137577, 28931.82722336, 28631.98578017, 
                 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22705.23480156, 
                 22447.8996166, 22264.0887702, 22174.48098258, 22082.57555938, 
                 21786.18056956, 21617.30435443, 21485.19030858, 21382.94552527, 
                 21295.63537323, 22046.96220789, 21295.63537323, 21295.63537323, 
                 21138.247336, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1385.47425474, 
                 0, 1602.60081705, 1556.64810545, 1392.36716148, 3000.71206748, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1978.26423438, 2320.6119358, 
                 1094.49363486333, 3091.13895388334, 3102.62713178334, 3392.12921486333, 
                 4266.37955305334, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 366.47287501, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 3281.02360824, 3215.54099421, 2963.9498982, 0, 0, 109.13769005, 
                 0, 0, 0, 342.34770142, 422.76494672, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 2735.33515799, 8044.02216558, 13422.78705836, 12846.08052778, 
                 11491.5505155017, 10873.56038235, 10873.56038235, 10298.00266956, 
                 10695.4936249, 9724.74259235, 9135.39906608, 8760.88446654, 8116.39768635, 
                 7506.37543986, 6933.11536265, 6340.32538301, 0, 0, 5744.08895, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 5744.08895, 0, 0, 5744.08895, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 5744.08895, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5744.08895, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 19899.82175838, 
                 11757.4882116095, 11488.1779, 12749.57983342, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 11488.1779, 
                 11488.1779, 5744.08895, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2743.37688252, 
                 2347.03474497, 2630.7927391, 6651.6550041, 6944.60354055, 6664.29199979, 
                 6447.16543748, 6184.08616357, 5926.75097861, 5690.09451387, 5478.71204051, 
                 5236.31148682, 5036.41719136, 4834.22526032, 4611.35460906, 4302.32262355, 
                 3990.99300246, 3745.1459954, 3515.3824374, 3332.72040879, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11488.1779, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 
                 24095.30432746, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 
                 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 23578.33632196, 22976.3558, 
                 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 
                 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 
                 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 
                 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558, 22976.3558))

qout_vector <- c(0, 0, 31.01808033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5563.72455697, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 956.96521907, 546.83726804, 
                 0, 20837.25707502, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 550.28372141, 0, 0, 0, 134.41168143, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1247.61611994, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2858.25866152, 0, 8.04172453000001, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 768.888820516669, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3950.45466080333, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 129.81641027, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 88.4589698299997, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 2759.46033158, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1428.05435083827, 3.37261550173279, 41.3574404399994, 
                 0, 0, 397.49095534, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5695.83860282, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 137.8581348, 259.63282054, 0, 0, 4949.10703932, 5035.26837357, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 523.86091224, 0, 0, 213.68010894, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5404.03888416, 5020.3337423, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 511.22391655, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 522.71209445, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7817.21811220046, 
                 0, 0, 786.94018615, 0, 205.63838441, 0, 0, 0, 5376.4672572, 0, 
                 5362.68144372, 5423.56878659, 5364.9790793, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 3196.01109178, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 180.36439303, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 62.03616066, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 360.72878606, 
                 0, 0, 1172.94296359, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 402.0862265, 0, 94.2030587799997, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 488.24756075, 398.63977313, 0, 327.41307015, 
                 135.56049922, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)


precipitation_fun <- approxfun(precipitation_vector, method = "constant", rule = 2) #Precipitation
mapp_fun <- approxfun(mapp_vector, method = "constant", rule = 2) #Component mass applied
igrow_fun <- approxfun(igrow_vector, method = "constant", rule = 2) #Day of cultivation cuycle
dw_fun <- approxfun(dw_vector, method = "constant", rule = 2) #Water depth
vw_fun <- approxfun(vw_vector, method = "constant", rule = 2) #water volume
qout_fun <- approxfun(qout_vector, method = "constant", rule = 2) #Water leaving the system


Model code
library(deSolve)

params <- list(
  covmax = 0.5,
  jgrow = 152,
  sa = 114881.779,
  kf = 0.24,
  kw = 0.046,
  ks_sat = 0.03,
  ks_unsat = 0.117,
  sol = 408,
  dt = 1,
  dinc = 0.05,
  dact = 0.1,
  kd = 2.1,
  css = 50,
  ksetl = 2,
  bd = 1.5,
  fc = 0.35,
  wilting = 0.24,
  MW = 1,
  fet = 0.2, 
  kmonod = 1e-8
)

pesticide_model <- function(time, state, params, precipitation, mapp, igrow, dw, vw, qout) {
  with(as.list(c(state, params)), {
    
    igrow_t <- igrow_fun(time)
    mapp_t <- mapp_fun(time) * 100
    vw_t <- vw_fun(time)
    dw_t <- dw_fun(time)
    qout_t <- qout_fun(time)
    P <- precipitation_fun(time)
    
    cover <- covmax * (igrow_t / jgrow)
    
    mfapp <- mapp_t * cover * sa
    mwapp <- mapp_t * (1 - cover) * sa * (dw_t > 0)
    msapp <- mapp_t * (1 - cover) * sa * (dinc / dact) * (dw_t == 0)
    
    sol_diff <- 0
    
    cw <- (mw / max(vw_t, 1e-10)) * (dw_t > 0) + 
          (mw / max(qout_t, 1e-10)) * (dw_t == 0 & qout_t > 0) 
  
    excess_sol <- pmax(cw - sol, 0)
    sol_diff <- excess_sol * vw_t
    cw <- pmin(cw, sol)
    
    mw <- (mw - sol_diff) * (dw_t > 0)
    ms <- (ms + sol_diff) 
    
    vsed <- sa * dact
    cs <- ms / vsed
    mout <- (qout_t > 0) * (qout_t * cw) * dt 
    
    ks <- ks_sat * (dw_t > 0) + ks_unsat * (dw_t <= 0)
    pos <- fc - wilting
    fds <- pos / (pos + (kd * bd))
    fdw <- 1 / (1 + kd * css)
    kdifus <- 69.35/365 - pos * MW^(-2/3)
    
    fpw <- (kd * css) / (1 + kd * css)
    msetl <- (ksetl * (fpw * cw) * dt * (dw_t > 0))
    
    mdifus <- (kdifus * sa * (fds * cs / pos - fdw * cw) * dt) * (dw_t > 0)
    
    mwdeg <- mw * exp(-kw * dt)
    msdeg <- ms * exp(-ks * dt)
    mfdeg <- mf * exp(-kf * dt)
    mwash <- mf * (1 - exp(-fet * P * dt))
    
    fb <- function(x) x / (x + kmonod)
    dMF <- (mfapp - mfdeg - mwash)
    dMW <- (mwapp - mwdeg + mwash - msetl + mdifus - mout)
    dMS <- (msapp - msdeg + msetl - mdifus)
    
    list(
      deriv = c(dMF, dMW, dMS),
      var_names = c(dw_t = dw_t, vw_t = vw_t, qout_t = qout_t, mout = mout, cw = cw, mdifus = mdifus, mwapp = mwapp, msetl = msetl, mwdeg = mwdeg, mwash = mwash)
    )
  })
}

timestep = 1

state <- c(mf = 0, mw = 0, ms = 0)
times <- seq(1, 365, by = timestep)
out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = pesticide_model, parms = params, hmax= 1/24,  method="ode45")

Update:
I have come around events to find a way to set mw to 0 but of course, this prevents me from correctly calculating the mout variable, i.e. the mass of the pollutant flowing out of the system. As I don't have the mass in the timestep I can't calculate the outflow concentration. Here is the code with which I have created the events in case it is helpful.
posfun <- function(t, state, parms) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parms)), {

    dw_t <- dw_fun(t) 
    if (dw_t == 0) {
      state["mw"] <- 0
    }
    return(state)
  })
}


out <- ode(y = state, 
           times = times, 
           func = pesticide_model, 
           parms = params, 
           events = list(func = posfun, time = times),
           hmax = 1/24, 
           method = "ode45")



You cannot set a state variable to zero in a model function, because the model function describes the derivatives. The time series of state variable is then the result of the integration. Besides of this, using an if or a condition like (dw_t > 0) is rarely a good idea.

After running your model and reading your question again, you may read more about floating point arithmetics, e.g. Is floating-point math broken?.

@tpetzoldt Could you suggest some alternative approaches for handling scenarios where I need to reset a state variable based on certain conditions?

It seems that your question did not attract much interest. There are several reasons: (1) it is normal that precision of floating point arithmetics is limited. Why one cannot get "exactly zero" is a FAQ. (2) A numerical solution of an ODE is always an approximation. It is unclear why you want a state variable to be exactly zero. (3) your example is too complex and the code too long. People answering questions invest their time voluntarily, so if something needs too much time to reproduce, it is unlikely to get an answer. So, please simplify your code as much as possible.
